# display charts using MVC, .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to display some charts on my mvc app but I'm having some errors.  I'm developing in localhost.  I have one cshtml file named ReportChart

```
@{
var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
    .AddTitle("Chart Title")
    .AddSeries(
        name: "Employee",
        xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
        yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
    .Write();
```

}

and another file that use that chart:

```
<body>
<h1>Chart Example</h1>
<p>The following chart is generated by the <em>ReportChart.cshtml</em> file:</p>
<p><img src="ReportChart.cshtml" alt="Cricketers" /> </p>
```

The only problem is that the webpage doesn't display any image :/

Comment: Are we supposed to know what ReportChart is?

Comment: @RobertHarvey i used this site to follow my code http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart

Comment: Does `ReportChart.cshtml` display a chart if you open it directly in the browser?

Comment: Ah, now I'm getting it.  **ReportChart.cshtml is not actually an image.**  You're trying to render a file as an image that is not an image.

Comment: ..Although that's exactly what the tutorial you linked says to do.  Sorry, but I'm stumped.

Comment: That tutorial is for ASP.NET Webpages, are you sure that's work for MVC ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it won't work in MVC. You should create chart in the controller action method:

```
 //I CUT THE CODE WHERE I construct string[] t1 and int[] t2 these are just arrays
  public ActionResult EfficiencyChart(string pid) {



            var myChart = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 600)
            .AddTitle("Employee's Efficiency")
            .AddSeries(
                name: "Employee",
                xValue: t2,
                yValues: t1)
            .Write();

            myChart.Save("~/Content/chart" + user.Id, "jpeg");
            // Return the contents of the Stream to the client
            return base.File("~/Content/chart" + user.Id, "jpeg");
        }
```

Then in the Razor view:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("EfficiencyChart", "NAME_OF_THE_CONTROLLER", new { pid = @Model.Id })" />
```

Comment: just one more question, if i want o query the db, i should do that in my controller?

Comment: @user2002274 Yes. If you want to fetch data directrly from db(through DbContext) it should be done in controller.

Comment: this works fine but the only problem is that this open one image.. i want to have my layout, and a couple of charts inside my layout with hiperlinks, and other stuff.. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

try it,

```
 <p><img src="@Url.Action("ReportChart")" alt="Cricketers"  /> </p>

      public ActionResult ReportChart()
            {
                return PartialView();
            }
```